# Question about Supermatrix algebra

Tags: supersymmetry, fermions, supergravity, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

This question is inspired from a reading of Appendix F of [P. van Nieuwenhuizen, Supergravity, Phys. Rep. 68 (1981) pp. 369-374](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157381901575).

Consider a "supermatrix"

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} A & B\\ C & D\end{array}\right)$$

where the Bose-Bose parts $A$ and the Fermi-Fermi parts $D$ are Grassmann even, and the Bose-Fermi parts $B$ and the Fermi-Bose parts $C$ are Grassmann odd.

The article says

> ..in $D-CA^{-1}B$ terms $CA^{-1}B$ are nilpotent

Does this mean $(CA^{-1}B)^2 = 0$? Is this  meant to be a trivial statement?

One way I can reason this is that $C$ and $B$ could each involve at most $4$ fermionic coordinates $\theta$ and $\bar{\theta}$ and any term involving more than $4$ $\theta$'s would vanish (for a $d = 4, \mathcal{N} = 1$ theory). So, $CA^{-1}B$ can have at most 4 $\theta$'s and squaring it would trivially give zero.

But is this also what the author meant by "nilpotency"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is true that physicists often talk about *$X$ being nilpotent* when they really mean that *$X$ squares to zero* $$X^2~=~0,$$ in particular in the topics with Grassmann-odd symmetries, such as, e.g., [Poincare supersymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) or [BRST symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRST_quantization).
2. But not in Ref.1. By *$X$ being nilpotent* is here meant the [standard mathematical definition of being nilpotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent): $$\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: ~~X^n~=~0.$$

References:

1. P. van Nieuwenhuizen, *Supergravity,* [Phys. Rep. 68 (1981) 369](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(81)90157-5); Appendix F.